# Grab first entity from a collection in HQL (NHibernate)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

Suppose I have a Class `Manager` with a (non-indexed) collection of `Employees`.  I want to return, say, all `Managers` whose newest `Employee` is untrained.  Rather than having to select the `Employee` with the max `StartDate`, thus having to compare all those dates, I would like to just grab the first result in the `Employees` collection, which will always be the most recent employee.  Is there a way for me to do this in HQL?

Equivalent of my current query:

```
select manager
from Managers as manager
join manager.Employees as employee
where employee.StartDate = (select max(emp.StartDate) from manager.Employees as emp)
and employee.Trained = 0
```

Instead of finding the most recent Employee via it's startdate, I'd just like to grab the first employee in the Manager.Employees collection and use that.

Thanks folks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an indexed collection (List), it's as easy as `manager.Employees[0]`.

If it's not, there is no such thing as "first".

See [14.8 Expressions](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-expressions)